# facebook login button is not showing to my blog

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

i am enabling Facebook login button to my blog by follow this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/

I've done everything perfect but its not showing i am getting these when i goto browser console.

> Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the
>   application id. all.js:56 FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling
>   FB.init().

what to do?

and i also integrate google+ sign in button and its working perfect check it in working here.
http://hashtaginside.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

You need an app id for your log-in workflow to work. To get one you must register as a Facebook Developer. Then after that go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and create a new app. Then you will be able to use Facebook log in.

Then for your log-in button change the src to

```
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/login_button.php?app_id={your_app_id}&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FLEdxGgtB9cN.js%3Fversion%3D40%23cb%3Dfd83dd978%26domain%3Dhashtaginside.blogspot.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fhashtaginside.blogspot.com%252Ff2e65db4e4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;locale=en_US&amp;max_rows=1&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=200
```

Where {your_app_id} is the app id Facebook gave you.

Once you have that if you need more assistance let me know I can take you further.

Comment: thanks for you reply , but it not worked :( i am still getting errors in console i configure everything well, i think google sign in button is more easy as you can i integrate it to my blog,
but facebook giving me error :(

i use this button,


`<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId= ID ";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`